# How to divide content with CSS even, odd?

Tags: html, css

I have a page with content like that.

```
#################################
#  __________________________   #
# |           |              |  #
# |          |               |  #
# |  text   |       IMAGE    |  #
# |        |                 |  #
# |_______|__________________|  #
#                               #
#  __________________________   #
# |           |              |  #
# |          |               |  #
# |  IMAGE  |        text    |  #
# |        |                 |  #
# |_______|__________________|  #
#################################
```

With my code like this:

```
<!-- <p> -> <image> -->
<div class="even_odd">
    <p></p>
</div>
<div class="even_odd">
    <img src="" alt="">
</div>

<!-- <image> -> p -->
<div class="even_odd">
    <img src="" alt="">
</div>
<div class="even_odd">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Now, I want to set default CSS:

When number is `odd`, it will set `text` to `float: left`, `image` to `float: right`.

When number is `even`, it will set `image` to `float: left`, `text` to `float: right`.

Currently, I must do like this:

```
.even_odd:nth-child(1), event_odd:nth-child(4), ..... many and many child .... {
   float: left;
}

.even_odd:nth-child(2), event_odd:nth-child(3), ..... many and many child .... {
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: Please check this link:-https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek Pandey was edited my question to clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I gather from OP's request is an alternating layout of img/div blocks. Here is an outline of the Snippet:

- `main.main` is the container in which everything resides within.

  - It's a column flex container.
- There are 3 `section.row`s

  - They are flex items of `main.main` and are flex containers as well.
  - Every odd ordered section is `flex-direction:row` by default.
  - Every even ordered section is `flex-direction:row-reverse`.
- There is an `img.img` and a `div.txt` in each `section.row`.

  - Every pair inhabiting an even ordered `section.row` is in reversed order.

**Note:** The important thing to remember about `nth` selectors is:

- They apply to an element's position among it's siblings and ancestors.
- The alternative `nth-of-type` will filter out other siblings that do not match the tag in the selector.

  - For example, if there were a mix of divs and sections and the selector was: `div:nth-of-type(even) {color:red;}` every even ordered div would be red regardless of how many sections there were.
  - If you used `div:nth-child(even) {color:red}` in the situation previously mentioned, the results would still make the divs red, but will count the sections as well (but will not apply the red text color).
  - They do not recognize class or any attribute selectors.

BTW, try to avoid `float`s they are fragile relics, get to know flexbox it is your friend.

#### SNIPPET

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: auto;
  background: grey;
}
section:nth-of-type(odd) {
  display: flex;
}
section:nth-of-type(even) {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.txt {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <section class='row'>
    <img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/000/fff?text=1' class='img'>
    <div class='txt'>TEXT</div>
  </section>
  <section class='row'>
    <img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/00f/eee?text=2' class='img'>
    <div class='txt'>TEXT</div>
  </section>
  <section class='row'>
    <img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/0e0/111?text=3' class='img'>
    <div class='txt'>TEXT</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are very welcome. If this answer resolved your problem, click the green **✔** of this post.

Comment: @Emran seem answer before you and his help me resolve my problem. I tested your answer and it working. So, I vote your question like another method to resolve problem.

Comment: And I read your question provides more information to another user can find more useful. You awesome!!!

Comment: Oh, didn't see that one, happy coding. :) Btw, it's not who's first, it's which is the best answer, but either way, thank you for the acknowledgement. :)

Comment: Should be that. Your answer have more information useful. Hope to help another user with an issue like me.

Answer (score 6):

We Try This CSS Selector.

```
selector:nth-child(odd) {
    property
}

selector:nth-child(even) {
    property
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```